# Bundled gem appears in Gemfile.lock but not available in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I'm looking to use a couple of new gems in my project, 'ruby-fftw3' and 'aubio'. The project has been happily working away and being extended but now every time I try and add a new gem it's unavailable when I try and call it.

The gems are listed in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'aubio'
gem 'ruby-fftw3'
```

When I run `bundle install` they are listed:

```
Using aubio 0.3.1
...
Using ruby-fftw3 1.0.2
```

Gemfile.lock also contains both items.

However, when I open `rails c` and try to use the gem they're unavailable:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'ruby-fftw3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):1
LoadError (cannot load such file -- ruby-fftw3)
irb(main):002:0> Aubio
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NameError (uninitialized constant Aubio)
```

It also appears that `Bundler.require(:default).collect(&:name)` does not contain either gem!

I've gone through the Gemfile and can't see any formatting errors and if there were any I don't think bundle install would create a lock file which included them.

Comment: doesn't work for me too (Rails 5, ruby 2.4.1). I'll return when I find something

Comment: > require 'aubio'
`LoadError: Could not open library '/usr/local/Cellar/aubio/0.4.4/lib/libaubio.dylib': /usr/local/Cellar/aubio/0.4.4/lib/libaubio.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` even though `gem install` was successful

Comment: You need to `brew install aubio` first. I think I’ve found my issue. I discovered that if I changed the name of the project directory it worked. Turns out stopping spring (which I didn’t realise was running) fixed the issue. Very weird. I don’t see why spring should interfere with new console session or gems in general